# BackgroundColor for all windows

Tags: c#, wpf, background-color

In my WPF-application, I want that the user can change the background color like he or she wants. How can I set the background color from the one window where I can set it to all windows in my app?

How can I manage this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can dynamically reference (using [`DynamicResource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms748942.aspx)) the same `SolidColorBrush` defined in the `Application.Resources` in the backgrounds of all windows, if you then replace this resource with another brush the windows will update.

Alternatively you could create a `Brush` property with change notifications somewhere (e.g. in some globally accessible settings in the `App` class) to which you can bind.

Comment: This is nice to know. For some reason I always thought that Brushes are immutable in .NET (I guess because Fonts are), but I was obviously wrong.

Comment: @Groo: Actually you are correct. Sorry, you should reference the brush via DynamicResource and switch it out completely, my memory was inaccurate

Comment: When I read your post, I went to MSDN to check if [`SolidColorBrush.Color`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.solidcolorbrush.color(v=VS.90).aspx) can be modified, and it actually does have a `set` accessor. I would expect that all forms should be explicitly invalidated, but why wouldn't it work?

Comment: @Groo: `SolidColorBrush` is [freezable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750509.aspx), once frozen it cannot be changed.

Answer (score 0):

You don't say whether its a web or desktop app., nor whether you're using MVVM pattern or not, but I would suggest that you set this in the style sheet for your application. This is then referred to in the XAML for each "window".

Comment: Unfortunately working with the theme styles usually does not work for windows because styles are not inherited and windows are created by inheriting from `Window`.